# Why the whole Torah is written as stories interrupted with Mitzvos and not the vice verse?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-study, parshanut-theory

After studying Gemmorah daily for 20 years, I come to ask, basically, why the whole Torah is written as a storyline, with the Miztvos interrupting it here and there, instead of the whole Torah being a Halachic compendium and the Torah stories being a part of our rich Oral tradition?

IIRC, according to all the mainstream interpreters (excluding the Kabbalic line that makes practically no use of the Gemmorah) **the purpose of the Torah is to give clear instructions of how to fix this world and fix ourselves for the purpose of bringing the World to Come**. Even if we can learn some good practices from those stories, it could be written far more clearly and practically as explicit instructions.

Instead, long pages bear seemingly no practical information (Nesi'im sacrifices, repetitions of stories, like Eliezer's), and tons of critical halachic information is missing (prohibition of relations with one's daughter) or learned indirectly (marrying by money - קיחה קיחה).

Comment: Yerushalmi Sanhedrin 4:2

Answer (score 7):

[Bereishit Rabbah 60:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.60.8?lang=bi):

> אָמַר רַבִּי אַחָא יָפָה שִׂיחָתָן שֶׁל עַבְדֵי בָּתֵּי אָבוֹת מִתּוֹרָתָן שֶׁל בָּנִים, פָּרָשָׁתוֹ שֶׁל אֱלִיעֶזֶר שְׁנַיִם וּשְׁלשָׁה דַפִּים הוּא אוֹמְרָהּ וְשׁוֹנָהּ, וְשֶׁרֶץ מִגּוּפֵי תּוֹרָה וְאֵין דָּמוֹ מְטַמֵּא כִּבְשָׂרוֹ אֶלָּא מֵרִבּוּי הַמִּקְרָא.‏
>
> R. Aha said, "The conversation of the servants of the forefathers' houses is more beautiful than the Torah of their sons. The passage of Eliezer takes up two or three columns and is stated and repeated. However, the rules regarding creeping creatures is a fundamental Torah rule, and the fact that its blood does not impart impurity as its flesh does is only derived from extra words used in the verse."

R. Ahron Lichtenstein explained this *medrash* [as follows](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA):

> בתורה ניתן למצוא שתי דרכי הנהגה. האחת מנוסחת בלשון מצווה, ומפרטת את המעשים השונים שעל האדם לנהוג בהם או לחדול מהם. השניה מיוצגת בדמותם של אנשים שמעשיהם, הנהגותיהם ואורחות חייהם אמורים לכוון את דרכנו. לעתים, הצגת הדמות החיה, משפיעה ומדריכה הרבה יותר מניסוח אורחותיה בדרך של מצווה. במיוחד נכונים הדברים לגבי המצוות שבין אדם לחברו, שלגביהן קשה לקבוע מראש גדרים ברורים ומדוייקים. אכן, התורה אינה מותירה שיקול דעת מוחלט לאדם כיצד ינהג ביחסיו עם בני האדם, ואף על פי כן אין היא פורטת את כל ההוראות שיכוונו את התנהגותו בכל מצב ומצב אליו ייקלע במהלך חייו.‏
>
> The Torah contains two sources of behavior. One is described in terms of *mitvot*, which details the various actions that a person should either do or refrain from doing. The second is represented in people whose deeds, behavior and lives are supposed to direct us. Often, presenting a living example can impact and affect much more than simple writing out their modes of behavior as *mitzvah*. This is certainly true with reference to interpersonal *mitzvot*, which are difficult to define *a priori* with clear and precise rules. Yes, the Torah does not leave a person to totally apply his own judgment as to how to behave with others. Nevertheless, it also does not spell out in great detail every instruction that will direct someone's behavior in every situation in which he finds himself during his life.

He goes on to explain how, for example, Yosef was prevented from sinning due to 'seeing' the image of his father, rather than remembering the laws of *arayot*.